# Answers getting deleted due to deleted questions

Tags: support

I have recently noted that a [question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/173316/why-is-phosphoric-acid-weak) that I had answered has been deleted by the Community bot along with which my answer was deleted too. Also I had no downvotes on my answer and it had 0 score until the deletion. Besides these, I have only three answers manually deleted upto date with them having a respective score of -1, -2 and -1.

However I have read on Meta SE that a frequent string of deleted answers could lead to banning from questioning or answering of the concerned account.

Do the answers that were deleted due to the parent question being deleted by the Community bot also are counted in this string of deleted answers that might lead to such a banning? I am so much concerned about it.

Comment: I don't think that it is currently much of a problem for your account. I think you still have good standing. As with the question ban, details of the algorithm are not fully disclosed.
The answer itself didn't have a down vote, so it might just count neutral.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of us know the workings of the question/answer ban. However, I would be very surprised if it penalised answers to deleted questions, especially if said answer had a positive score. Questions, even half-decent ones, get deleted quite regularly, so it would be somewhat unfair to penalise an answerer based on this.

The issue with deleted posts and the Q/A ban is that people often think that if they get downvoted, they'll just 'erase' this by deleting their answer. That isn't relevant to this post, so I don't really think it'll be a problem.

As for 'rescuing' the answer, you haven't actually lost it, because you can still see the question. (Well, I can see it because I have >10,000 rep; but according to my research on meta.SE, I think you should be able to as well, because you posted an answer. Since you could see that it was the Community bot that deleted it, I'm guessing I'm correct about that.) So you can still click on 'edit' to get the answer back ...

... and sure, nobody *else* can see it, but if you feel really strongly that this was something worth sharing, then you can re-ask the question and self-answer it. Obviously, you will want to try to avoid the issues that caused the original question to be closed. In this case, I think the following is good enough; it's mostly taken from the end of the existing question.

> [Is there] a correlation between how many hydrogens an acid could donate and the strength of its first ionisation? [For example, phosphoric acid is relatively weak compared to sulfuric acid. Does this generalise to] triprotic acids usually [being] weaker than diprotic acids? Is that something to do with the bonds they have?

Now, in principle, the original question could have been edited, undeleted, and reopened. That's a discussion for another time...

Answer (score 4):

I don't have an answer to your main concern (about the question/answer ban). Questions get deleted automatically for a variety of reasons. I think the rule that kicked in for the post in question was:

> If the question was closed more than 9 days ago, and ...
>
> ```
> not closed as a duplicate
> has a score of 0 or less
> is not locked
> has no answers with a score > 0
> has no accepted answer
> has no pending reopen votes
> has not been edited in the past 9 days
> ```
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted. (These are termed "abandoned
> closed" in the code.)
>
> This check is run every day across all sites.

Here is the list of reasons: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/auto-deleted-questions. It links to another post about what to do about this if you want to "save" your answer.

Comment: [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers), it is stated that answers with score less than or equal to -1 can be deleted by the community but I am afraid it doesn't address my query.

Comment: @Proscionexium The question was deleted. There is no way to keep the answer if the question is no longer there.

Comment: Yeah I understand that but it is quite overwhelming that one cannot _save_ one's decent answer due to someone else's question getting deleted. Also it seems to affect one's profile adversely.

Comment: *Questions get closed automatically for a variety of reasons.* I'm pretty sure you mean deleted. Nothing gets closed automagically.

Comment: @pros Well, questions can be undeleted, but there would have to be a good reason for that.